# Deployment fails using Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

This is my first CI/CD attempt using Github Actions and for some reason, my deployment keeps failing. I have my Github repo with the following files.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1.1K Sep  7 21:40 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1.1K Sep  7 18:06 README.md
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  132 Sep  8 18:09 deploy_to_aws.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  275 Sep  8 18:05 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxr-x 6 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Sep  7 23:27 flexdashboard
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  359 Sep  7 19:30 shiny-server.sh
```

Now I am trying to build, deploy, and run the shiny application on a cloud instance (the shiny application runs when I manually run it on the cloud). So I set up this workflow in Github actions

```
name: Deploy EC2
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: checkout
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - name: Run a one-line script
            run: echo Hello, world!
          - name: Install SSH key
            uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
            with:
              key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
              name: id_rsa # optional
              known_hosts: ${{ secrets.KNOWN_HOSTS }}
          - name: rsync over ssh
            run: ./deploy_to_aws.sh
```

Here are the contents of the `deploy_to_aws.sh` of the deployment script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Starting to Deploy...'
cd Illumina-mRNA-dashboard 
docker-compose up -d
echo 'Deployment completed successfully'
```

I am now getting this error.

```
 shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
Run ./deploy_to_aws.sh
  ./deploy_to_aws.sh
     shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
/home/runner/work/_temp/48d3ea81-a97b-45d1-894f-177e77cb8ae5.sh: line 1: ./deploy_to_aws.sh: No such file or directory
##[error]Process completed with exit code 127.
```

I don't understand why it keeps telling me that `deploy_to_aws.sh`  doesn't exist

Comment: Put `ls -la` in your step before executing `deploy_to_aws.sh` to check the contents of the current folder

Comment: Exit code 127 either means the file doesn't exist OR your script doesn't have execution permissions. Try to use bash directly or set permissions before.